# объект с коллекцией ссылок на детей

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

я пытаюсь начать делать игру. при этом решил в самом внешнем объекте сделать коллекцию ссылок на все дочерние объекты. я это делаю для того чтобы любой дочерний объект мог простым способом обратиться к любому другому дочернему объекту

так выглядит мой самый внешний объект:

```
var Game = function(options) {
  this.objectsPointers = {
    f: 1,
    levelObj: 'undefined',
    playerObserverObj: 'undefined',
    targetObserverObj: 'undefined',
    enemyObserverObj: 'undefined',
    fieldObj: 'undefined',
    playerObj: 'undefined',
    targetObj: 'undefined',
    enemyObj: {}
  },

  this.options = {
    level: options.level || 1,
    fieldWidth: options.fieldWidth || 20,
    fieldHeight: options.fieldHeight || 20
  };

  while (this.options.level < 10) {
    break;
    this.objectsPointers.levelObj = new Level;
  }

  console.log('you win!');
};
```

а так выглядит отдин из дочерних обектов:

```
var Level = function() { 
  console.log(this.objectsPointers.f);
};
```

как видите, ссылка на него хранится в app.objectsPointers.levelObj . таким образом, когда объект level хочет вывести значение this.objectsPointers.f , то скрипт, не найдя его в самом level, будет искать в более внешней области видимости

проблема в том, что этого не происходит и в результате я получаю в консоли следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of undefined

вот [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58yotmoh/3/)

помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтобы в объекте level заработало вот это:

```
console.log(this.objectsPointers.f);
```

Comment: что-то вы совсем запутались что именно хотите получить

Comment: @cyklop77 `var Level = function() { 
  console.log(this.objectsPointers.f);
};` никогда не увидит ничего внутри Game обращаясь по this. в JS, в отличие от других языков у this очень особенное поведение. В данном случае Level может увидеть свойства только обратившись как Game.objectsPointers, потому как this внутри Level зависит от способа как его вызвали и более ни от чего !

Comment: @cyklop77 Если вы у себя в Level сделаете просто console.log(this) вы увидите что он не указывает никуда. Можете  при создании Level передавать ему создающую Game в качестве параметра и пусть он ее сохраняет у себя внутри, в замыкании.

Comment: @Mike, я пробую сделать по вашему совету. но в результате в level удаётся вывести объект game, но не удаётся вывести его свойства. сообщение об ошибке осталось такое же как в моём основном вопросе.
var Level = function(gameObj) { 
  this.gameObj = gameObj;
  console.dir(this.gameObj);
  console.log(this.gameObj.objectsPointers.f);
};

Comment: @cyklop77 И создаете вы объект Level из Game как `new Level(this)` ?

Comment: @Mike, да. именно так: 
this.objectsPointers = {
  f: 1,
  levelObj: new Level(this)
}

Comment: @cyklop77 Создаете то вы его так, только вот new вы вызываете прямо в объявлении `objectsPointers`, а он не будет создан пока JS не получит все значения, которые нужны для его создания. Т.е. ваш new вызывается _до_ того, как objectsPointers начнет существовать. Вы сначала создайте вашу структуру, а потом добавляйте в нее свойство как `this.objectsPointers.levelObj=new Level(this)`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. всё получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ - это использовать один базовый класс для "дочерних" объектов, либо создать общий интерфейс с обязательными свойствами, методами и т.д.
Тогда любой дочерний элемент сможет получить доступ в коллекции родительского объекта к любому дочернему объекту. Тогда вам достаточно будет иметь в дочернем объекте только ссылку на родительский объект.

Comment: но я именно это и пытался реализовать -  один базовый класс для "дочерних" объектов. базовый 'класс' в моём случае это Game

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас не объявлено свойство 'f'. Мне так кажется.

Comment: Судя по ошибке у него this указывает совершенно не на game, А определить куда он указывает можно только увидев откуда и в каком контексте он вызывает Level, чего в вопросе не видно. Но скорее всего он вызывается так, что this=window, поэтому там и нет структуры содержащей f